# Why is my e-mail address sometimes considered invalid by websites?

Tags: outlook.com, registration

It happens sometimes, when I sign up for a forum or a website that I get told my e-mail address is invalid. It looks like this: `name_lastname_@hotmail.com`.

Is there any reason why this might be considered invalid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably the underscore before the @ sign. It's not technically invalid, but it's not especially common, and I can easily see that badly written format checkers would flag it as invalid (you're not allowed to have a full stop before the @, so they might generalise that to all punctuation characters).

Comment: Aha! That might indeed explain it.

Comment: Some sites limit your use of the free email accounts, because they can be viewed as throwaway accounts.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Here in Belgium, I would say the majority uses Hotmail or Gmail. Don't know about other countries. Doesn't seem like a smart move then :)